# What is the most physically efficient way to change pitch within a vocal register?

Tags: technique, voice, physiology

What is the best method to vary notes when I sing ?

- by stretching vocal cords ?
- by increasing/decreasing my air pressure ?
- by using both at the same time ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. It sounds like you want to know the body mechanics of changing from one note to another. Is that correct, or are you looking for something else?

Comment: yes its correct

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [How does it feel (or where) to change the pitch while singing?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/111870/70803).

Answer (score 1):

You're kind of asking a question that could be simple in a way that makes it difficult to understand... I assume you mean moving up/down notes to sing basic songs?
I mean, if you can say a sentence in your normal voice out loud, and then find the note on the piano that you usually hover around and play it, you can probably figure out how to manipulate your voice to match that note. Maybe find some kind of vocal pitch monitor to tell you what note you speak on.
Then, you can record yourself playing that note on a piano (you can find apps and websites with virtual pianos if you don't have one) and moving up and down the piano around that note and trying to match it on a neutral syllable (like ah.) For the most part, singing a note within your range and jumping to other notes around it should not take any complex techniques with air pressure or... the stretching of vocal chords? It's mostly muscle memory and you should get the hang of it while singing more often. Also, if you play back that recording, unless you're completely tone deaf, you should be able to tell if you're doing it correctly. I personally learned it through trial and error.